# How to optimize change detection in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have two components, and a service. I think the issue is that when I click out from a routed component's view to elements from different components (a matMenu and an input field), the routed component seems to re-render itself. This really only becomes a problem (so far at least) if said routed component is generating errors (in this case GET errors). So by repeating the same actions, the console can get filled with lots of errors. I'd like to understand what happens in this case, and how I could make optimizations.

Component A is using matMenu,

```
<nav class="navbar">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center">
        <a mat-icon-button href="" class="icon-button">
          <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
        </a>
        <span fxHide.gt-sm>
          <button mat-icon-button class="icon-button" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"> 
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </span>
        <span fxHide.lt-md>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"><b>Alkatrészek</b></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><b>Szolgáltatások</b></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><b>Vásárlási információk</b></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><b>Elérhetőség</b></button>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
          <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let item of kategoriaList$ | async"
           (click)="setCategoryPage(item.nev)">{{item.nev}}</button>
        </mat-menu>
        <ng-container *ngIf="alkatreszList$">
          <app-search-bar #searchBar [alkatreszList$]="alkatreszList$"></app-search-bar>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

where

```
setCategoryPage(category: string) {
    if (category !== this.categoryPageService.getCategory()) {
      this.categoryPageService.setCategory(category);
      this.categoryPageService.setShowCategoryPage(true);
    }
  }
```

is calling the service

```
export class CategoryPageService {
  private showCategoryPageSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  showCategoryPage$ = this.showCategoryPageSubject.asObservable();
  category: string = '';

  getCategory(): string {
    return this.category;
  }

  setCategory(categoryIn: string) {
    this.category = categoryIn;
  }

  setShowCategoryPage(showCategoryPage: boolean) {
    this.showCategoryPageSubject.next(showCategoryPage);
  }
  
  constructor() { }
}
```

Then, routing takes place from component A to component B

```
<body>
  <img *ngIf="!(showCategoryPage$ | async)" src="assets\20170822_180636.jpg">
    <app-category-page *ngIf="showCategoryPage$ | async"></app-category-page>
</body>
```

In component B there is a carousel within a grid, which gets populated with data from a database (just like in component A)

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.alkatreszList$ = this.service.getAlkatreszList();
    this.kategoriaList$ = this.service.getKategoriaList();
    this.autoTipusList$ = this.service.getAutoTipusList();
    this.kategoria.push(this.categoryService.getCategory());
    this.kategoria = this.kategoria.map((value: string) => value.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
    this.searchService.setCategoryFilter(this.kategoria);
    this.filteredAlkatreszek$ = this.searchService.getFilteredAlkatreszek(this.alkatreszList$);
    this.showCategoryPage$ = this.categoryService.showCategoryPage$;
  }

calculateRows(items: any[]): any[][] {
    const maxColumns = 6;
    const numRows = Math.ceil(items.length / maxColumns);
    const rows: any[][] = [];
  
    for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      rows.push(items.slice(i * maxColumns, (i + 1) * maxColumns));
    }
  
    return rows;
  }
  
  getRowItems(items: any[], rowIndex: number): any[] {
    const maxColumns = 6;
    const rowItems = items.slice(rowIndex * maxColumns, (rowIndex + 1) * maxColumns);
  
    return rowItems;
  }
```

and in the template

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showCategoryPage$ | async">
  <div>
    <p>IT WORKS</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container text-center" *ngIf="(filteredAlkatreszek$ | async) as filteredAlkatreszek">
      <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of calculateRows(filteredAlkatreszek); let i = index;">
          <ng-container>
              <div class="col" *ngFor="let item of getRowItems(filteredAlkatreszek, i)">
                  <div id="imageCarouselCategoryPage" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
                      <div *ngIf="item.kepek.split(';').length > 1" class="carousel-indicators">
                        <button type="button" [attr.data-bs-target]="'#imageCarouselCategoryPage'" [attr.data-bs-slide-to]="i" [class.active]="i === 0" *ngFor="let img of item.kepek.split(';');
                        let i = index" [attr.aria-label]="'Slide ' + (i + 1)"></button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-item active" [class.active]="i === 0" *ngFor="let img of item.kepek.split(';'); let i = index">
                              <img class="d-block w-100" [src]="'https://localhost:7094/images/' + img" style="max-height: 100vh; max-width: 100%;">
                              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                  <h5>{{item.nev}}</h5>
                                  <p>{{item.ar}}</p>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#imageCarouselCategoryPage" data-bs-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                      </button>
                      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#imageCarouselCategoryPage" data-bs-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
          </ng-container>
      </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

The input field I mentioned is itself routing to yet another component (component C) from component A.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="alkatreszList$">
 <app-search-bar #searchBar [alkatreszList$]="alkatreszList$"></app-search-bar>
</ng-container>
```

So, why component B is re-rendering (if this is what happens) when elements from component A / component C are clicked? How is this behaviour related to change detection?

Answer (score 0):

Angular's change detection is triggered when events occur. When change detection is triggered, Angular checks the component's template for any updates and applies them if necessary. https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

Use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` or localize Change Detection.

Also make sure that the data shared between components A, B and C is immutable, by using immutable data structures.

In the latest version(16), angular also introduce signals https://angular.io/guide/signals and in the next version signal components .